# Creating a Multi Tenancy / Saas and having trouble desiging the database for users

Tags: php, database, symfony, multi-tenant, saas

I'm building an SAAS with a single database. `Tenant` in this case is called `site`.

[image]

I want to achieve what Stackexchange does where it has a global login as well as a stackoverflow/softwareengineering/etc login. I'm not sure how to store users. A user can have many sites and sites can have many users. The problem with designing a JoinTable is that the user roles are stored in the User table (im using Symfony3.4). I want separate roles per site/tenant.

Another problem I'm trying to figure out is how to go about logging in. I'm using oAuth2 and to login in I sinply call `{{url}}/oauth/v2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&username=admin&password=pass`. How should I make the user log in to a specific tenant/site? Do I add site_id to the query parameters?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Voting to close this, as the question is just far too broad for a single, concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad, so I'll take a stab at it.

If you are building out a network of sites, each site would ideally have it's own database. This will ensure sandboxing and the ability to easily migrate a site to it's own infrastructure if needed due to scaling or security concerns.

When dealing with user authentication, it sounds like you'll want a single secure user store that acts as the oauth2 server and each of the sites act as a Oauth client.  You'll want to use the Authorization Code flow grant type in OAuth.

Essentially, a user visits Site A.  Site A sees they are not logged in via the site's session. It redirects to your OAuth server which shows a login (think of the google login). Since Site A also passed in a callback url, once you've signed in, the OAuth server knows where to redirect the user, along with the valid token information. Then Site A takes that token and exchanges it for an access token on the server-side so now you've got authentication data on Site A.

If you are going to implement your own OAuth handshaking, you should utilize an existing server/client library.  For PHP, you can look at the League OAuth server library, or use Laravel Passport, if you're using Laravel.  There are other similar packages for other frameworks out there.